# React Transition Group - In a simple ToDo list, how to animate the upwards moving elements?

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, css-transitions, react-transition-group

With React Transition Group, i know how to create enter and exit transitions for a task in a todo list when it gets added or removed from the list. However i have absolutely no idea how to create transitions for all the tasks that come afterwards when they move up in the list. You can see the problem here:

[image: remove item animation]
(taken from this site: https://typeofnan.dev/how-to-animate-items-out-of-an-array-in-react/)

Someone has an idea how to achieve this?

The code so far for the todo-list:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
import './styles.css';

const initial = ['Walk dog', 'Sweep floors', 'Do homework'];

export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(initial);

  return (
    <TransitionGroup component="ul">
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <CSSTransition key={todo} timeout={700} classNames="item">
          <li>
            {todo}{' '}
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setTodos(todos.filter((t) => t !== todo));
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </li>
        </CSSTransition>
      ))}
    </TransitionGroup>
  );
}
```

```
.item-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 700ms ease-out;
}
```

So far i tried adding "transition: all 700ms" to the tasks (list-item), but it didn't work as the the tasks don't get repositioned. The whole component gets rerendered with the new tasks thus i don't know how to tackle this at all...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `nodeRef` in each `CSSTransitions`. Look at the example below from `React-transition-group` documentation:

```
<TransitionGroup className="todo-list">
      {items.map(({ id, text, nodeRef }) => (
        <CSSTransition
          key={id}
          nodeRef={nodeRef}
          timeout={500}
          classNames="item"
        >
          <ListGroup.Item ref={nodeRef}>
            <Button
              className="remove-btn"
              variant="danger"
              size="sm"
              onClick={() =>
                setItems((items) =>
                  items.filter((item) => item.id !== id)
                )
              }
            >
              &times;
            </Button>
            {text}
          </ListGroup.Item>
        </CSSTransition>
      ))}
    </TransitionGroup>
```